# How to update HTML5 audio duration property?

Tags: html, html5-audio

On a web page, there will be list with audio file, some of which will not have correct metadata for duration.

I've tried to just select that that and assign new value to duration, but it does not change it (as if duration was readonly property).

**How to override/change duration property of html5 audio tag?**